# What is the difference in usage between nominalized nominal verbs and nouns forming the same nominal verbs?

Tags: nuances, nominalization, morphology

In the following sentence, why is すること needed?

> システムメンテナンスにより休止**すること**があります。

Can it simply be:

> システムメンテナンスにより休止があります。

Comment: As you might already know, システムメンテナンスにより**休止することがあります** and システムメンテナンスによる**休止があります** (≂システムメンテナンスにより休止します) have different meanings. The former means that the service **might be** (and might not be) unavailable due to system maintenance, whereas the latter is saying the service will certainly be unavailable due to system maintenance.

Comment: @Chocolate 休止がある still has a room to interpret that it might not happen. Such ambiguity itself is a difference, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> システムメンテナンスにより休止があります。

It couldn't be, instead you should say;

> システムメンテナンスによる休止があります。

【**Question**】
In the following sentence, why is すること needed?
システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}することがあります。

【**Answer**】

At first, the given sentence could be broken down like this:
システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}することがあります。
＝「システムメンテナンスにより」＋「休止{きゅうし}する」＋「こと」＋「が」＋「あります」。

★日本語{にほんご}の文法{ぶんぽう}ルール１（Japanese Grammatical Rule 1）
(a) In the phrase 「＊＊があります」 meaning "there is/are ＊＊," the part 「＊＊」 must be 「名詞{めいし}（noun）or 名詞{めいし}句{く}（noun phrase）」.

★日本語{にほんご}の文法{ぶんぽう}ルール２（Japanese Grammatical Rule 2）:
 (b) 「＊＊＊＊」＋「に」＋「よる」＋「休止{きゅうし}」＝名詞{めいし}句{く}（noun phrase）
 (c) 「＊＊＊＊」＋「に」＋「より」＋「休止{きゅうし}する」＝動詞{どうし}句{く}（verb phrase）

where ＊＊＊＊＝システムメンテナンス

These equations could be written grammatically more precisely:
 (b)' 「＊＊＊＊（＝名詞{めいし}）」＋「に」＋「よる（＝因{よ}る（meaning 原因{げんいん}・理由{りゆう}）＝ラ行{ぎょう}四段{よんだん}活用{かつよう}連体形{れんたいけい}）」＋「休止{きゅうし}（＝名詞{めいし}）」＝名詞{めいし}句{く}
 (c)' 「＊＊＊＊（＝名詞{めいし}）」＋「に」＋「より（＝因{よ}り（meaning 原因{げんいん}・理由{りゆう}）＝ラ行{ぎょう}四段{よんだん}活用{かつよう}連用形{れんようけい}）」＋「休止{きゅうし}する（＝動詞{どうし}）」＝動詞{どうし}句{く}

By the Rule 2, the following two phrases are allowed:
 (d) システムメンテナンスによる休止{きゅうし}
 (e) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}する

but the phrase written below is not allowed.
 (f) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}

If you want to use the phrase (d) and (e) in the Rule 1, (d) has no problem but (e) must be changed into noun phrase by adding 「こと」 before applying the Rule.

Now you get (g) newly:
 (g) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}すること

I'd like to mention this in passing. 「場合{ばあい}」 could be also used instead of 「こと」 to change the verb phrase (e) into noun phrase (h) with the same meaning as (g).
 (h) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}する場合{ばあい}

Then you will get (g) and (h) along with (d), which are applicable three phrases to Rule 1 successfully.

At last you'll get three beautiful Japanese;
 (i) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅし}することがあります。
 (j) システムメンテナンスによる休止{きゅうし}があります。
 (k) システムメンテナンスにより休止{きゅうし}する場合{ばあい}があります。

I think the last sentence is used most in business world.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the grammar please?

Comment: @Nutkin I'm a well educated and native Japanese. But, I'm sorry to say, to tell your the truth, I couldn't explain the correctness/incorrectness of those sentences grammatically.

Comment: This is a very helpful response, but it focuses on the problem with ～により versus ～による, while the OP's specific question was about 休止することがあります versus 休止があります.  Could you address that part of the question as well?

Comment: @snailplane Now I understand what you tell me, and it is true that  I didn't answer it to the questioner. Give me a little time to consider, because it is a difficult answer to make the questioner understand completely with my poor grammatical knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  Is (i) more formal than (j) ?

Comment: @Nutkin (j) is grammatically correct, but it is not natural.  (i) is more natural than (j), and it is a normal expression before thinking of its formality.

Answer (score 0):

In システムメンテナンスにより休止することがある, the システムメンテナンスにより part modifies the verb 休止する.

Whereas in システムメンテナンスにより休止がある, the システムメンテナンスにより modifies the verb ある this time.

It's not a major difference but when you want to express that システムメンテナンス is the cause of 休止, it's slightly more natural to choose the form in which システムメンテナンスにより modifies 休止. (システムメンテナンスによる休止 is this case.)